# startActivityForResult desde un adaptor y recibir los datos en el fragment

Tags: java, android

Tengo lo siguiente:

- MainActivity
- Fragmento1 con recylerview
- SimpleAdapter

Des de el `RecyclerView.Adapter` al hacer click envio un `Intent` con `startActivityForResult`

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(item.getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), 0x600);
```

Para capturar el resultado lo hago a la `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() called with: requestCode = [" + requestCode + "], resultCode = [" + resultCode + "], data = [" + data + "]");
}
```

Aquí todo correcto, recibo el resultado perfectamente, pero me gustaría que el resultado lo compute el `Fragmento1` para realizar cambios en el `RecyclerView`.

Veo que en Fragmento se puede usar `onActivityResult` pero no captura nada.

¿Hay alguna forma de delegar el onActivityResult de la actividad hacia al fragmento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mi solución**
Para delegar el resultado hacia todos los fragmentos que están operando.

Del `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() called with: requestCode = [" + requestCode + "], resultCode = [" + resultCode + "], data = [" + data + "]");
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

En el Fragmento, se recibe de la misma forma.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        //@todo computar el resultado
    }
}
```